# How to use @BlobOutput or @TableOutput in java azure functions

Tags: java, azure-functions

The official docs seem to be missing the documentation around using these outputbindings, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-java does not give any examples of using these bindings.

Has anyone had any luck using these? I am looking to achieve something similar to:

```
@FunctionName("consumeNodeInfo")
fun consumeNodeInfoFromQueue(@QueueTrigger(queueName = "nodeinfos", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage", name = "nodeinfos", dataType = "binary") addedNodeInfo: ByteArray,
                             @TableOutput(name = "networkmap", tableName = "networkmap") table: OutputBinding<SignedNodeInfoRow>) {
    table.value = SignedNodeInfoRow(addedNodeInfo)
}

open class SignedNodeInfoRow(val signedNodeInfo: ByteArray) {
    val rowKey = signedNodeInfo.deserialize<SignedNodeInfo>().raw.hash
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**@BlobOutput:**

Please refer to my sample code:

```
@FunctionName("blob")
public String functionHandler(
            @QueueTrigger(name = "myQueueItem", queueName = "walkthrough", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage") String queue,
            @BlobOutput(name = "blob", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage" , path = "samples-java/2.txt") OutputBinding<String> blob) {

        blob.setValue(queue);
        return queue;
}
```

`AzureWebJobsStorage` is configured in the `local.settings.json`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "<your connection string>",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": ""
  }
}
```

***function.json:***

```
{
  "scriptFile" : "..\\fabrikam-functions-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "com.fabrikam.functions.Function.functionHandler",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "queueTrigger",
    "name" : "myQueueItem",
    "direction" : "in",
    "connection" : "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "queueName" : "walkthrough"
  }, {
    "type" : "blob",
    "name" : "blob",
    "direction" : "out",
    "connection" : "AzureWebJobsStorage",
    "path" : "samples-java/2.txt"
  } ],
  "disabled" : false
}
```

---

***@TableOutput:***

Just for summary:

We could check the properties in the `function.json` from this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table#output---configuration). 
Never forget the property named `RowKey`.

***sample code:***

```
@FunctionName("consumeNodeInfo")
fun consumeNodeInfoFromQueue(@QueueTrigger(queueName = "nodeinfos", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage", name = "nodeinfos", dataType = "binary") addedNodeInfo: ByteArray,
                             @TableOutput(name = "networkmap", tableName = "networkmap", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage", partitionKey = "nodeInfos") table: OutputBinding<SignedNodeInfoRow>) {
    val nodeInfo = addedNodeInfo.deserialize<SignedNodeInfo>()
    table.value = SignedNodeInfoRow(nodeInfo.raw.hash.toString(), addedNodeInfo.toBase58())
}

data class SignedNodeInfoRow(val RowKey: String, val arrayAsBase58String: String)
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, this did help - I was able to reverse engineer the TableBinding too.

Comment: @Stefano Thanks for your sharing and i summarized in my answer. You could mark the answer for others' reference on the forum.Thx.

Comment: Can we set the filename for blob dynamically?

Answer (score 1):

So after much investigation, it turns out you have to have a property named "RowKey"

**The capital R is *very* important**
Below is an example of a working implementation.

```
@FunctionName("consumeNodeInfo")
fun consumeNodeInfoFromQueue(@QueueTrigger(queueName = "nodeinfos", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage", name = "nodeinfos", dataType = "binary") addedNodeInfo: ByteArray,
                             @TableOutput(name = "networkmap", tableName = "networkmap", connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage", partitionKey = "nodeInfos") table: OutputBinding<SignedNodeInfoRow>) {
    val nodeInfo = addedNodeInfo.deserialize<SignedNodeInfo>()
    table.value = SignedNodeInfoRow(nodeInfo.raw.hash.toString(), addedNodeInfo.toBase58())
}

data class SignedNodeInfoRow(val RowKey: String, val arrayAsBase58String: String)
```